# UDP video streaming latency - OPENCV python

Tags: python, sockets, opencv, udp

I have streaming video UDP, but the packets are delayed and disordered.
Here is my code for reference which I have taken from opencv website.

But when I give Socket.Stream to use TCP connection it streams fine and the frames are continuous.

Server.py

```
import socket
import numpy
import time
import cv2

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 999
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


s=b''

while True:

  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(46080)

  s += data

  if len(s) == (46080*20):

    frame = numpy.fromstring (s,dtype=numpy.uint8)
    frame = frame.reshape (480,640,3)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    s=b''

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord ('q'):
    break
```

Client.py

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import cv2

UDP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
UDP_PORT = 999
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320)
#cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240)
def xrange(x):

  return iter(range(x))
while (True):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  d = frame.flatten()
  s = d.tostring()
  for i in xrange(20):
    sock.sendto(s[i * 46080:(i + 1) * 46080], (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: "but the packets are delayed and disordered" Welcome to the world of UDP!

Comment: Klaus D... I gone to so many solutions but none solves the issues..Either help mw increase the TCP latency or UDP 's loss of packets

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `client.py` script is sending out UDP frames (much) faster than the `server.py` is piecing them together. I am not sure why this is the case. Perhaps after increasing the size of byte `s` after every iteration, Python needs to find a new place to store `s`, which causes it to miss frames sent from `client.py`. However, one way to sync them is to tell the `client.py` to send after `server.py` acknowledges receipt of the frame.

In the below code, `server.py` will listen for a start-of-image transmission via `b'eframe'`. `server.py` would the consecutively reply `client.py` with `b'n'` to cue sending of the next frame. `client.py` would notify the end-of-image by sending `b'eframe'`

**server.py**

```py
import socket
import numpy
import time
import cv2

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 999
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


s=b''

while True:

  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(6) # b'eframe' is 6 byte long

  if data == b'sframe':
    while True:
      sock.sendto(b'n', addr)
      data, addr = sock.recvfrom(46080)
      if data == b'eframe':
        break
      s += data

  if len(s) == (46080*20):

    frame = numpy.fromstring (s,dtype=numpy.uint8)
    frame = frame.reshape (480,640,3)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    s=b''

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord ('q'):
    break
```

**client.py**

```py
import socket
import numpy as np
import cv2

UDP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
UDP_PORT = 999
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320)
#cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240)
def xrange(x):

  return iter(range(x))
while (True):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  d = frame.flatten()
  s = d.tostring()

  sock.sendto(b'sframe', (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
  for i in xrange(20):
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1) # b'n' is 1 byte long
    if data == b'n':
      sock.sendto(s[i * 46080:(i + 1) * 46080], (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1)
  sock.sendto(b'eframe', (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```